Custom themes are not getting applied to certain applications in Ubuntu 24.04
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 and trying to use custom themes. But themes are not getting applied to file manager and some other applications. Even though I have installed User Themes gnome extension and enabled. Also I don't know why that file control is not visible for shell themes. Where you can pick a local theme from directory (as someone asked the question as well).
Here are my screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/KVRyE8j
Any help?

Did you manage to solve this?

@Pithikos negative. No clue yet. Perhaps it is because many applications migrated to GTK 4 and themes are no longer compatible.

Look inside the theme folder. There's a gtk4 folder if the theme supports it. Copy the contents of the folder to ~/.config/gtk-4.0 and logout and back in.
